# Use LWJGL 3 From Command-Line

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to implement LWJGL 3 from the command-line, but I'm running into some problems. I put LWJGL.jar in my "classes" and "sources" directories, but when I try to compile, it complains that all the LWJGL classes don't exist. Thank's for any help!

Comment: What is the command you compile with?

Comment: javac -cp lwjgl.jar *.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, I know, I'm answering my own question, but here goes. This is the command  I'm using now to usr LWJGL (and other libraries):

In order to compile:
javac -cp lib/*.jar SourceFile.java

In order to run:
java -cp lib/*.jar:. -Djava.library.path=native/* ClassFile

This is what works for me. I hope this helped!